# Download files from Amazon S3 in batches using the AWS Command Line Interface (CLI)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have one use case where I have around 40 million objects located in an Amazon S3 bucket. I want to download them, process them and re-upload them to another Amazon S3 bucket. First issue, I can't download them all of them at once due to shortage of hard disk space.

I want to download them in batches. For example, I want to download 1 million objects, process them, re-upload them and delete them from local storage. After that, I will download the next 1 million objects and repeat same process.

Is it possible to download files from an Amazon S3 bucket using AWS CLI to download in batches?

Comment: No, it doesn't have a concept of "batches". Perhaps you can do it by directory or prefix (eg `a*`, then `b*`)?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have everything available in one directory unfortunately. All files have same extensions as well. So can not even use filter option.

Comment: Can you divide them by name, such as all files starting with `A`, then `B`, etc? If not, you'll need to write your own code create 'batches'. You might want to create the initial list using [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a daily or weekly CSV file listing all objects in a bucket.